# Regex to match subdomains other than "www"

Tags: php, regex, url

Hey guys. Right now I have this regex on my PHP app:

```
$regex = '#^(www\.)*([^www][a-z0-9-]+)\.tanlup\.local$#';
```

Here is what I need it to do:

```
MATCH www.something.tanlup.local  
MATCH something.tanlup.local

NOT MATCH www.tanlup.local  
NOT MATCH tanlup.local
```

The problem is that when I have a subdomain starting with a "w", it doesn't match! Does anyone knows why and how could I make it better?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building overly complex regular expressions for one-off situations like this is self-defeating. You might have better luck building a very generic regular expression and black listing certain domains:

```
$regex = '/^([-\w]+.)+tanlup.local$/';
$disallowed = array ('www.tanlup.local', 'tanlup.local');

if (preg_match($regex, $str) && false === array_search($str, $disallowed) {
  // success
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a [negative lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^.*(?<!^www)\.tanlup\.local$
```

Note that not all regex engines support lookbehind, but I believe PHP does.

Comment: This fails for `not-www.tanlup.local`.

Answer (score 0):

[^www] doesn't do what you think it does.  You're saying you don't want a 'w' character.

Comment: You forgot to say why this doesn’t do that. The `[ ]` introduce a list of characters and NOT a sequence of characters (as normal parenthesis).

Comment: And how do I say that I don't want the sequence of three w's?